# Example of a measure space with infinite measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I'm having a little trouble solving a problem from my Real Analysis class.

The problem is from p238, "Lebesgue integration on Euclidian Space" by Frank Jones.

Q.  Give an example of a measure space such that $\mu(X) = \infty,\ and\ f\in L^p(X)$ for some $1 < p < \infty \implies f\in L^1(X) $

My intuition is that this problem has to do with sigma-finite measures, but this book does not formally define sigma-finite measures in this chapter (it does on later chapters).

Would appreciate any help/hints on this problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $X=\{a,b\}$, with $\mu\bigl(\{a\}\bigr)=\infty$ and $\mu\bigl(\{0\}\bigr)=0$. Then\begin{align}f\in L^p(X)&\iff f(a)=0\\&\iff f\in L^1(X).\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the example! Apparently, this question was way more trivial than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial example: Take the sigma algebra to be only empty set and X itself. Then $f\in L^p$ iff $f=0$, thus $f\in L^1$.